# Remove duplicate package installation, when "Package [] is not installed, so not removed" and make: *** No rule to make target 'uninstall'

Tags: package-management

I accidentally installed the same package twice:

```
$ whereis agda
agda: /home/me/.local/bin/agda /home/me/.cabal/bin/agda
```

I cannot remove it with sudo apt:

```
$ sudo apt remove agda
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'agda' is not installed, so not removed
```

I went into one of the package dirs and tried

```
$ sudo make uninstall
make: *** No rule to make target 'uninstall'.  Stop.
```

How can I get rid of these packages completely?

Comment: https://plfa.github.io/GettingStarted/#install-plfa-and-the-agda-standard-library

Comment: stack install --stack-yaml stack-8.8.3.yaml

Comment: Edit that information in your Question above. Do not bury important information in comments. Make your question clear: You seem to be looking for how to uninstall software that you installed using the `stack` command. Google suggests looking at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38636436/how-to-uninstall-a-haskell-package-installed-with-stack

Comment: Is this Ubuntu if so what version?

Comment: the version is 18.04

Comment: @user535733 why did you give my question negative feedback?

Comment: I gave your question *constructive* feedback, to help make your question answerable. Better quality questions lead directly to better help for you.

Comment: The feedback you gave was of no help. I don't think you read it. Thanks for trying but don't post feedback just for the sake of posting something.

Comment: What is agda? How it was installed? Why do you think it was installed from APT?